# Unusual javascript piece of Code showing on my site when I do inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

On one my page a piece of code is showing when I do inspect element and I have not written this code anywhere. It is still showing when I clear the console.

```
function hack() {
    function hacker() {
        console.log(myvar);
    }
    var myvar = 2;
    hacker();
}
var myvar = 1;
hack();
hacker();
```

This is the peice of code which I am getting. Is it related to hacking ? Is someone hacked my site and inserted their code ?

Comment: Check what browser plugins/add-ons have you installed

Comment: Looks like someone has been testing how global scope works in javascript. That code in itself looks pretty innocuous.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? The user explicitly provides details of question, and there is a problem to solve.

Comment: Can we see it for ourselves? Is the site live for us to see?

Comment: @Esko Sorry I can't show it you as it is my ofc work. I think 'Tushar' is  right it is because of some plugin installed on my browser because when I check it with other browser or in incognito mode this piece of code is not shown. The problem is it is showing only on a particular page not on all the pages.

Comment: @ben-hillier but this code is not written anywhere in my code.

Comment: @tushar I think you are right it is because of some browser add-on. but why it is showing only on a particular page?

Comment: @esko Even if I share the url with you then also it is not guarantee that you will also experience the same issue because in my other browser it is working perfectly. The only thing which I can do is I can share my screen with you .